# How to add multiple entry points to CRA

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a normal CRA not ejected. I want to add a way that when I hit a certain URL it loads a different public/index.html page and then reactdom renders a "different" Main component to start the app

Is this possible without ejecting and how would I do it?

or

If I do eject, what is the most simple way to do this?

Google doesn't seem to render much helpful stuff

Comment: Duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480066/multiple-entry-points-by-using-create-react-app/63497447#63497447 Follow the link for other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to have multiple entry points you need to change the webpack configuration of `create-react-app`

You can use [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to override the existing webpack configuration of create-react-app, If not you need to eject from create-react-app and change the configuration

Here is a [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1084) for discussion regarding the same

Four steps to add multiple entry points to create-react-app
(say we add an admin.html):

1. Eject the project

   `npm run eject`
2. Add multiple entry to `webpack.config.dev.js`

   ```
   entry: {
    index: [
     require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
     require.resolve('./polyfills'),
     require.resolve('react-error-overlay'),
     paths.appIndexJs,
    ],
    admin:[
      require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
      require.resolve('./polyfills'),
      require.resolve('react-error-overlay'),
      paths.appSrc + "/admin.js",
    ]
   },
   output: {
     path: paths.appBuild,
     pathinfo: true,
     filename: 'static/js/[name].bundle.js',
     chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
     publicPath: publicPath,
     devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
     path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath),
    },
   ```
3. Modify HtmlWebpackPlugin add a new plugin node:

   ```
       new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         inject: true,
         chunks: ["index"],
         template: paths.appHtml,
       }),
       new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         inject: true,
         chunks: ["admin"],
         template: paths.appHtml,
         filename: 'admin.html',
       }),
   ```

   4.webpack Dev Server rewrite urls `/config/webpackDevServer.config.js`:

   ```
    historyApiFallback: {
     disableDotRule: true,
     rewrites: [
       { from: /^\/admin.html/, to: '/build/admin.html' },
     ]
    }
   ```

Comment: ok trying this. how does webpack know which html file to load though based on the url?